# Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'object'

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, properties, assign

```
function marge(obj1: object, obj2: object) {
    return Object.assign(obj1, obj2);
}

const margeObj = marge( {firstName: "John"}, {lastName : "Doe"} );
console.log(margeObj.firstName);
```

Typescipt throwing error at last line while trying to get property firstName of mergeObj.

> Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'object'.

Both obj1 and obj2 are object and adding return type object does not fixed this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't understand what type the merge function should return. You can specify the arguments with generics and then merge them in the return type with the `&` intersection operator:

```
function marge<T extends {}, S extends {}>(obj1: T, obj2: S): T & S {
    return Object.assign(obj1, obj2);
}

const margeObj = marge({firstName: "John"}, {lastName: "Doe"});
console.log(margeObj.firstName);
```

The returned type will be the intersection between `T` and `S`, all properties in the object arguments will be available in the return type.

`X extends {}` simply constrains the argument to an object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've to use an interface like this.

```
function marge(obj1: object, obj2: object) {
    return Object.assign(obj1, obj2);
}
interface user {
    firstName:string;
    lastName:string;
}
const margeObj:user = marge( {firstName: "John"}, {lastName : "Doe"} );
console.log(margeObj.firstName);
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use existential quantification, like:

```
function marge<T, U>(obj1: T, obj2: U): T & U {
  return Object.assign(obj1, obj2);
}
```

This says, for the params `obj1` and `obj2` there exists some types, `T` and `U`, respectively.  The function doesn't know what those types are, but it does know it should return an intersection type from them.

Comment: This works as long as the arguments are objects, it's now  possible to call the `marge` function with non object arguments

Comment: This is true.  Whilst `Object.assign()` won't complain, the OP did mention the type `object`.  Your answer addresses this correctly.  Eg `marge<T extends {}, U extends {}>`